# Return multiple sums of relationship weights using cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph with one node type 'nodeName' and one relationship type 'relName'. Each node pair has 0-1 'relName' relationships with each other but each node can be connected to many nodes.

Given an initial list of nodes (I'll refer to this list as the query subset) I want to:

1. **Find all the nodes that connect to the query subset**

I'm currently doing this (which may be overly convoluted):

```
MATCH (a: nodeName)-[r:relName]-()
WHERE (a.name IN ['query list'])
WITH a
MATCH (b: nodeName)-[r2:relName]-()
WHERE NOT (b.name  IN ['query list'])
WITH a, b
MATCH (a)--(b)
RETURN DISTINCT b
```

2. **Then for each connected node (b) I want to return the SUM of the weights that connect to the query subset**

For example. If node b1 has 4 edges that connect to nodes in the query subset I would like to `RETURN SUM(r2.weight) AS totalWeight` for b2. I actually need a list of all the b nodes ordered by totalWeight.

No. 2 is where I'm stuck. I've been reading the docs about FOREACH and reduce() but I'm not sure how to apply them here.

Speed is important as I have 30,000 nodes and 1.5M edges if you have any suggestions regarding this please throw them into the mix.

Many thanks

Matt

Comment: Hi hewgreeen. Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question is a bit confusing. I suggest you: 1) share a snapshot of your data model 2) create a [console](http://console.neo4j.org/) with sample data and the expected result. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need so many `Match` statements? You can specify `a` nodes and `b` nodes in single `Match` statement and select only those who have a relationship between them.

After that just return `b` nodes and sum of the weights. `b` nodes will automatically be acting as a group by if it is returned along with aggregation function such as `sum`.

```
MATCH (a:nodeName)-[r:relName]-(b:nodeName)
WHERE (a.name IN ['query list']) AND NOT((b.name IN ['query list']))
RETURN b.name, sum(r.weight) as weightSum order by weightSum
```

Comment: I had tried to use one match but my AND NOT wasn't working properly for me and returned some of the query nodes in the b node list. Which lead me down my convoluted path. But this is perfect. Exactly what I needed. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can simplify that query a bit.

```
MATCH (a: nodeName)
WHERE (a.name IN ['query list'])
WITH collect(a) as subset
UNWIND subset as a
MATCH (a)-[r:relName]-(b)
WHERE NOT b in subset
RETURN b, sum(r.weight) as totalWeight
ORDER BY totalWeight ASC
```

Since `sum()` is an aggregating function, it will make the non-aggregation variables the grouping key (in this case `b`), so the sum is per `b` node, then we order them (switch to DESC if needed).

Comment: This also works perfectly. I didn't know how to use 'collect' or 'unwind'. So thanks for that! I'll be interested to see which solution is fastest when applied to my large graph. Thanks so much.

Comment: Make sure you add an index so your initial match becomes quick (you'll be able to confirm that by running an EXPLAIN on your query, you should see a NodeIndexSeek if it's working)